# Boot Directly to Program, Launch GUI on Exit

Tags: boot, emulation

I have been looking around for an answer and feel like there must be an easier way.  I pretty much want to disable the GUI and launch directly to a specific program.

Basically I would like to launch emulation station with as little as possible running in the background.  Then, on exit, either have a terminal to launch the standard gui or set it up to launch automatically when emulation station closes.

Thinking power button direct to emulation station with no GUi present until emulation station is stopped.

Wishful thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Not so wishful if you turn the question around: instead of disabling the GUI, install the [minimal system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) (it has no GUI) and make the login to your application work (nail that down first)

Afterwards, if you're satisfied without the GUI (automatic log out and everything) install the GUI, set the auto-log-in to a different user (who has a GUI) and just switch between two users (TTY and GUI)

I've personally never done an auto-login for a TTY user before, but I don't see why it would be impossible.